# Home directory in CDH 5.10.0

Tags: sql-insert, cloudera-cdh

I am running CDH 5.10.0 VM

When I create .sql files using gedit in the terminal, into /home/cloudera, I can see the sql file is being created in `Desktop-> Cloudera's Home`. But the same is not appearing when I use `hadoop fs -ls /home/cloudera`

Similarly, when I execute `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO DIRECTORY /home/cloudera/somefolder`, it is not showing physically in `Desktop -> Cloudera's Home`. But it is being displayed when I use- `hadoop fs -ls /home/cloudera`

Is it a permission issue? or my VM is corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop file system is different from your OS file system(local filesystem) so the path `Desktop-> Cloudera's Home` is completely different with `/home/cloudera` in your HDFS.
Hive in Cloudera is configured to use HDFS by default so the query you issued :

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO DIRECTORY /home/cloudera/somefolder
```

ran using HDFS not your local file system.

Comment: But when I create a file using the following command, it saves the file in Desktop -> Cloudera's Home.

gedit /home/cloudera/somefile.sql

This file is not visible when issued ```hadoop fs -ls /home/cloudera````

Comment: when you create a file using gedit, it saves that in your local file system. if you want to see that in HDFS you have to put that file in HDFS using this command `hadoop fs -put /path/in/linux /hdfs/path` now Hadoop file system knows about your file

Comment: with `hadoop fs -ls /home/cloudera` you actually query HDFS not your local file system

Comment: you're welcome! if this answers your question please accept that as an answer

Comment: Yes I did. Here is the summary of what I understood. This may help others if this is correct.

1) "gedit" saves the file in the local file system which is also being called in Hive (hive -f filename).

2) INSERT OVERWRITE INTO DIRECTORY saves the output into HDFS which is different than the above (in other words, not in the local file system).

Comment: yes, for more information about Hadoop, check the book `Hadoop the definitive guide`